# How to show + and - sign in alert box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are three variables as follows

```
var a=1;
var b=-2; 
var c=4;
```

If I performed following options

```
var Res=a*b*c;
```

Or

```
var Res=a+b+c;
```

Then if result is a -ve value show - in alert box and if result is a +ve
value show + in alert box

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=1;
var b=-2; 
var c=4;

var Res1=a*b*c;

var Res2=a+b+c;

function alertPlusOrMinus(n) {
    if( n < 0 ){
        alert('-');
    } else {
        alert('+');
    }
}

alertPlusOrMinus( Res1 );
alertPlusOrMinus( Res2 );
```